# var not always set when clicking link in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my `index.html` i have a `JQuery` `var` which i need to set when the user clicks an option from the left hand menu and its needed to show/hide fields depending on the selection made as the page is shared between 3 pages but displays different fields depending on the option.

But i have an issue when sometimes when the option is selected, its not setting the `var` as expected then after a few other clicks, it then decides to play ball and set it, then when ever it wants, it will stop again.

There no errors what so ever so not sure how to track or stop it.

**JQuery**

```
$('li').on('click', function (event) {
    selectedLinkId = event.target.id.toLowerCase();

    // Admin menu option clicked
    if ($(this).is($("li[name*='admin']"))) {
        selectedLink = 'adminMenuOption';
    }
    // Reseller menu option clicked
    else if ($(this).is($("li[name*='reseller']"))) {
        selectedLink = 'resellerMenuOption';
    }
    // Channel menu option clicked
    else if ($(this).is($("li[name*='channel']"))) {
        selectedLink = 'channelMenuOption';
    }
    // Customer menu option clicked
    else if ($(this).is($("li[name*='customer']"))) {
        selectedLink = 'customerMenuOption';
    }
    // Any other menu option clickedf
    else {
        selectedLink = 'generalMenuOption';
    }

    $('#mainSearchSection').show();
})
```

**Part of HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills flex-column" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" id="adminSearchLink" name="adminOptions">
        <div class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center option pl-6">
            Search for
            <i id="adminSearchMenuIcon" class="material-icons ml-auto mr-0">arrow_drop_up</i>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" name="adminSearchOptions">
        <a id="adminSearchCustomerLink" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center option" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
            <span class="ml-5 pl-4">Customer</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" name="adminSearchOptions">
        <a id="adminSearchNumberLink" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center option" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
            <span class="ml-5 pl-4">Number</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" name="adminSearchOptions">
        <a id="adminSearchResellerLink" class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center option" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false">
            <span class="ml-5 pl-4">Reseller</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Console.Log Output**

[image]

**Other Page JQuery Which Reads The Var**

```
var selectedLinkId;
if (selectedLinkId.includes('reseller')) {
        $('#accStatusCol, #companyNameCol, #nameFieldCol').show();
        $('#nameField').focus();
    } else if (selectedLinkId.includes('channel')) {
        $('#accStatusCol, #companyNameCol, #nameFieldCol').hide();
    } else if (selectedLinkId.includes('customer')) {
        $('#accStatusCol, #companyNameCol').show();
        $('#companyNameField').focus();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you declaring `selectedLink` and where are you using the initialised variable?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt This is being used for another page and is working correctly with no issues what so ever.  This `var` populates everytime without fail. It's the `selectedLinkId` that sometimes is not captured for some reason. I also tried adding the `event.target.id.toLowerCase();` to each `IF` and again it sometimes does not populate

Comment: you bound the click to the li and not all your li have ids so that is probably why `event.target.id` is not setting the var, but it's not obvious what var you are talking about or what you are console logging, please can you create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: I don't understand, It's always working for me https://codepen.io/vincent-d/pen/LwYLar
Can you provide css please?µ
EDIT, I think there is another function with a compatibility issue with the binded event

Comment: The problem is that you're sometimes clicking on the `<span>` and sometimes on the `<a>`, outside the text. Only the latter has an `id`. Use `$('li a').click(...` and `selectedLinkId = $(this).attr('id').toLowerCase();` instead. See: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4xapcj6v/

Comment: @Pete by bounding the `id` to the `li` it has stopped completly registering the id of the `li` clicked on

Comment: @ChrisG Cheers. Can you post your comment as an answer please as this seems to work perfectly

Comment: sorry, thought you were using `currentTarget` instead of target - if you are wanting the a id then I would probably change the binding to the a and use current target, then you can also prevent the default action of the a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to want to get the id of the clicked `<a>` element. However the event is bound to the `<li>` element.

When you use `event.target` it will give you the element that you clicked. Because events are bubbling it is not always the same element but can be any of the children of the element that the event handler is bound to. So sometimes you get the `<li>` element, sometimes the `<a>` element and sometimes the `<span>` element. If you want to get the id of the first a element all the times you can do `$(this).children('a').first().attr('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're sometimes clicking on the `<span>` and sometimes on the `<a>`, outside the text. Only the latter has an id.

Use `$('li a').click(...)` and

```
selectedLinkId = $(this).attr('id').toLowerCase();
```

This way, `this` always refers to the `<a>`, and getting the `id` from that never fails.

The non-jQuery variant is to use `event.currentTarget.id.toLowerCase()`, which always refers to the element that the listener was attached to as it bubbles up the tree.